# Countable paracompactness, normality and locally countable open covers

Tags: gn.general-topology, paracompactness

(repost from the topology Q&A board)

I have a (T_1), Normal, countably paracompact space X. I would like to know if every locally countable open cover of X (i.e. an open cover such that every x in X has a neighbourhood which intersects only countably many members of the cover) has a locally finite refinement.

My suspicion is that the answer is a resounding no, but every time I try to construct a counterexample it starts to seem more plausible.

If the answer *does* turn out to be yes I'd love to know if it generalises from aleph_0 to arbitrary cardinals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Caryn Navy's thesis under Mary Ellen Rudin she constructed several spaces that are normal, countably paracompact and paralindelöf (every cover has a locally countable refinement) but not paracompact.
All such spaces provide counterexamples (we can refine a cover without a locally finite refinement to a locally countable one and then we cannot continue...)

I'm not sure (as I do not have access to the PhD-thesis in question, and I only know it from references like http://www1.elsevier.com/homepage/sac/opit/10/article.pdf) whether these examples are all under extra set-theoretic assumptions (like MA + non-CH) or whether there are absolute ones as well.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Even if there are only examples under extra hypotheses it serves to nicely close down several lines of reasoning that I was pursuing into dead ends (and actually is sufficiently strong sounding that one of the counterexamples might suffice to close down the entire conjecture, which would be interesting).

I've (hopefully - details were difficult to find) dropped Caryn an email to see if she has a copy of the thesis she can send me. If she does, want me to forward you a copy? 

Comment: Yes, I would be interested. I have always liked these covering properties. Hopefully a digital copy or a published paper of these results exists. 

Comment: ok. Will let you know if I manage to track down a copy.

As far as I can tell this was never published - I saw reference to an "upcoming" paper, but it doesn't seem to have ever come.

I did find a reference in the topology proceedings from 1980 (puzzling given that the thesis was published a few years later. Oh well) referencing "Caryn Navy's construction of assorted para-Lindelof, non­ paracompact spaces, both in ZFC and under the axiom that there is a Q-set (implied by MA + ,CH)", so if this statement is accurate no extra axioms are needed.

Comment: UMI will sell you a copy (paper) for USD44.  http://disexpress.umi.com/dxweb and search for "Caryn Navy".

Comment: So they will, thanks.

I'll wait and see if either of the feelers I sent out turn up a hint and then buy a copy off there.

Comment: I saw that a space by Navy is described in detail in chapter 16, paragraph 6, of the Handbook of Set Theoretic Topology. It's normal, paraLindelöf, and not collectionwise normal (but collectionwise Hausdorff, as this follows from regular and paraLindelöf). No word on countable paracompactness there. No extra assumptions.

Comment: I have an old xerox copy of Caryn's dissertation.  If you're unable to get ahold of a copy, let me know and I'll see if I can't dig it up and help you out.

Comment: Example 5.2.1 in Caryn's thesis is a space Y constructed without any extra set-theoretic assumptions which is: T_1, zero-dimensional, normal, has character 2^\omega_1 (therefore not a Moore space and does not have a \sigma-disjoint or \sigma-locally countable base), para-Lindelof, metacompact, countably paracompact, but is not collectionwise normal (hence not paracompact).

Cheers,

Comment: Apollo: Sorry, missed your comments earlier. Thanks for the offer.

I've finally managed to get a hold of a copy and have scanned it and uploaded it. If anyone else interested, you can download it here: http://drmaciver.com/docs/paracompactness-in-paralindelof-spaces.pdf

Comment: David- No problem.  Thanks for posting the scan --- it's nice to have an e-copy (mine is a 20 year old xerox...) Cheers